# .NET, ITEXTSHARP, CHECK IF PDF IS A PORTFOLIO

Tags: .net, pdf, itext

Trying to use ITEXTSHARP/VB.NET to cycle through PDF's and check for portfolios. Not had much luck finding any specific documentation to deal with this, and came to a rather round-a-bout way (that ended up failing and giving a false positive on at least some PDFs with Bookmarks). So clearly the attribute I'm checking is not the correct one!

Here's my (failed) code as a starting point:

```
PDFDoc = New PdfReader(PDFToCount)
Dim Cat As PdfDictionary = PDFDoc.Catalog
Dim PDFNames As PdfDictionary = Cat.GetAsDict(PdfName.NAMES)

If PDFNames IsNot Nothing Then 
'this seems to catch portfolios, but it also caught at least a few bookmarked PDF's
end if
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* I ended up finding the solution. At least it's now working correctly in my small sample set. My original code was close, but I changed

```
Dim PDFNames As PdfDictionary = Cat.GetAsDict(PdfName.NAMES)
```

to

```
Dim PDFNames As PdfDictionary = Cat.GetAsDict(PdfName.COLLECTION)
```

otherwise the code remains the same and it looks like I'm getting the results I wanted. Hopefully that helps someone in the future... and hopefully I am correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to "Roughly" test a bunch of files in Windows you can run this command.

It is not a robust test as can false negative on some names but reduces (fast filters out) the files for a more thorough manual / **iText** / or other programmable test.

[image]

**Remember to double up** on %f (%%f) when using in a .cmd or .bat file

```
for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir /b *.pdf') do @(echo/ && find "/Collection" "%f" >nul && echo PORTFOLIO= "%f"|| echo NOT Portfolio or Error "%f")
```